# How to multiply database data by an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multiplication

I took off time to go through the array documentation and I learnt the different functions possible and found
array_walk_recursive()
as a good fit for what I want to do. But I still have some short-coming. Please can someone give this piece of code a try?

I want to:

- multiply my database data (a multidimensional array, $a2) by a an associative array, $userdata.
- A function does the  multiplication once and adds into an array which is summed and returned, as is seen below.
  This function instead multiplies all the array elements to my database values which is not what I want.

  ```
  $newValue = array();

  function myfxn(&$value,$key, $data)
  {
    $value = $value * $data;
    /*
    *************** The problem *********************
    ######## This function simply does ($a1['green']: 58 * 10 * 5.5)     #######

    I want each $data to multiply $value once and the product fed in an array, and be summed before being output as $newValue
    so I use this:
    ###############################################
    $value = $value * $data;

    $newData[] = $value;

    $newValue = array_sum($newData);

    ###############################################  
    But print_r($newValue); outputs an empty array.
    */
  }

  $a1=array("green"=>58,"red"=>25, "yellow"=>24);
  $a3=array("green"=>0.58,"red"=>0.25, "yellow"=>16);

  $userData = array(10, 5.5);

  $a2=array($a1,$a3);

  foreach(userData as $data):
      array_walk_recursive($a2,"myfxn", $data);
  endforeach;
  ```

Comment: I'm sure it can be done using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) or [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). But I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Update the question, indicate what is the input data and show the expected outcome.

Comment: Is $newData initialized before adding array elements to it?